# Multi-Dimensional Intersection Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

All,

I have a problem I need to solve and I don't know exactly how to do it efficiently. Suppose I have a collection of objects with multiple properties, and each property can take multiple values.

For instance, in pseudo-code an object could look as follows:

```
Object.Color  
Object.Size  
Object.Sides  
Object.Dimensions
```

I want to be able to get all objects in a collection which match a set of colors, a set of sizes, a set of sides and a set of dimensions.

Right now, my code is basically if Object.Color in ColorSet and Object.Size in SizeSet and ... and Object.Dimensions in DimensionsSet then I mark the object for processing (by using a dictionary).

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Can I create a data structure or algorithm that will help me solve this problem efficiently?

Cheers!

Comment: If you know the relative frequencies of each value for each property, you can reorder the comparisons to get better expected time per comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do just one such query, there's not that much you can do. Instead, I'll assume you want to do multiple such queries.

Create dictionaries mapping from the properties to sets of objects with those properties. For example, with colors, you might have mappings from `Red` to `{obj1, obj2, obj3}` and `Blue` to `{obj4, obj5}`. Do this for each property (color, size, sides, dimensions).

You then express your query on the collection as a whole. Object.Color in ColorSet becomes the union of the corresponding sets for the colors in ColorSet. Requiring both a color and a size becomes the intersection of the sets of objects with those colors and sizes.

This can be more efficient because you only need to check objects that could have all the properties, e.g., if you're interested in `Blue` objects, you can immediately exclude all the objects in the `Red` set.

Comment: Awesome! That was one of my ideas but I thought it might be slower overall. Thanks!